# Is there and easy way to go from 1000 psi to 45 psi without a complicated pressure regulator

Tags: pressure, valves

I have a C02 tank that is filled at 1000 psi. it's got a duel pressure regulator that allow you to dial it down to 45 PSI. Is there a simple way to regulate pressure from 1000 psi to 45 ( non adjustable ). I understand the theory of how a pressure regulator works, just wondering if there is an inline way to do this.

Comment: You could buy a fixed pressure regulator, it will likely be more expensive than the set up you have now.

Comment: simple, yes.  Cheap and safe, no.   There's no market for fixed-output regulators, so you'll have to get a controllable unit.

Answer (score 2):

As far as engineering systems go, it doesn't get much simpler that a pressure regulator; single or double. The mechanical feedback is solid solution.

[Wiki link for pressure regulator operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_regulator#Operation) (for future readers reference)
[image]

There are other ways to regulate pressure with various tradeoffs.

1. For a fixed flowrate you could size an orifice to reduce the pressure to 45psi. This is not technically regulation however because any change in temperature or flowrate will greatly change the pressure. That would not be a safe or reliable solution.
2. An orifice and a pressure relief similar to a [zener power regulator](http://vlab.amrita.edu/?sub=1&brch=282&sim=1207&cnt=1) where the orifice would restrict the flow and the pressure relief would bleed any unused gas to atmosphere. That would be a very wasteful solution.
3. Use a high-speed electric on-off valve in combination with an electronic controller to turn the flow on and off at different duty cycles to hit a target pressure measured by a pressure transducer on the output stream. This is similar to [PWM in electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation). It has been explored for [use in hydraulics](http://hydraulicspneumatics.com/other-technologies/pwm-unconventional-way-regulate-pressure). The main problem with this method is that it is expensive and it is hard to dampen all the pressure oscillations for a steady output.